# How to keep an active link highlighted throughout - Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone help me with a script that will keep selected links highlighted?

```
<div id="productnav">
<nav>
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="<?php echo $prefix; ?>pages/one.php?category=1" id="navelement1"<?php if ($c == 1) echo ' class="current"';?>>One</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $prefix; ?>pages/two.php?category=2" id="navelement2"<?php if ($c == 2) echo ' class="current"';?>>Two</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $prefix; ?>pages/three.php?category=3" id="navelement3"<?php if ($c == 3) echo ' class="current"';?>>Three</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $prefix; ?>pages/four.php?category=4" id="navelement4"<?php if ($c == 4) echo ' class="current"';?>>Four</a></li></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Below code only keeps the first clicked link highlighted, as soon as you select another item on selected page, it no longer remains active.

```
 Array.prototype.forEach.call(
     document.querySelectorAll('#productnav a[href]'), 
     function(t) { 
        var hr = t.href.split("/").pop();
        if (window.location.href.indexOf(hr) > -1)
            t.className = 'active'; 
        else
            t.className = '';
     }
  );
```

The CSS here

```
#productnav ul li a.active { border-right: solid 8px rgb(200,10,50);  text-decoration: none; background-color: #4E5765; !important; }
```

Thanks...

Comment: Please compress your code to one snippet, you do not need 3

Comment: Please, write HTML only instead of PHP in the snippet.

Comment: have you debugged to see why some links may not be passing your check at indexOf? You're comparing the HREF to see if it includes the current page URL and highlighting those links that do. It could be that only 1 link is successfully passing that test and getting assigned "active" class. Have you inspected the elements to see if "active" class is added?

Comment: Have you tried any of the code snippets I gave you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery to add the active class:

```js
function activeClass() {
  var fullCurrentURL = window.location.href;
  var CurrentURLparts = fullCurrentURL.split("/");
  var CurrentURLindex = CurrentURLparts.length - 1;
  var CurrentURL = CurrentURLparts[CurrentURLindex];
  console.log(CurrentURL);

  $('.navbar-nav > li a').each(function() {
    var fullLinkURL = $(this).attr('href');
    var LinkURLparts = fullLinkURL.split("/");
    var LinkURLindex = LinkURLparts.length - 1;
    var LinkURL = LinkURLparts[LinkURLindex];
    if (LinkURL === CurrentURL) {
      $(this).parents("li").addClass("active");
      $(this).closest("ul").css('display', 'block');
    }
  });
}
activeClass();
```

```css
#productnav ul li.active  a {
 border-right: solid 8px rgb(200,10,50); 
 background-color: #4E5765;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav id="productnav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li><a href="/about" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
     <li><a href="/js" title="JavaScript">JavaScript</a></li>
     <li><a href="/contact" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Didn't thought about this approach :) nice one!

Answer (score 1):

Selector

```
const selector = `nav a[href^="/${location.pathname.split("/")[1]}"]`;
```

jQuery

```
$(selector).addClass('active');
```

Vanilla js

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))
    .forEach(a => a.classList.add('active'));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's impossibile because when the user clicks a link, the page changes and JavaScript can't "remember" which links user have clicked before, just because the script has been reloaded.

You can:

- Store the clicked links in Browser Memory / Cookie;
- Use asynchronous page loading with XHR and jQuery;

Comment: Hello Syncro, you maybe right about using a cookie as nothing else (above) worked for me. Would you be able to give me a hint on how to java code after embedding a cookie?

Comment: Do you mean javascript?

Answer (score 0):

If you can add an *active* class to the list item containing the link to the current page, through PHP, do:

```css
.navbar-nav li.active a {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav id="productnav" class="navbar navbar-default">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="/about" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="/contact" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

If you want a Java Script solution for adding the *active* class, tell me.